# Spring 3 MVC and Apache Tiles 2 Integration Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tiles

I have been trying to integrate Spring (3.0.4 and 3.0.5) MVC with Apache Tiles (2.1.2,2.1.4 and 2.2.2) to no avail. In every case i get the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/startup/BasicTilesInitializer

According to the Tiles documentation, BasicTilesInitializer has been deprecated. I figured the latest version of Spring's [TilesConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer.html) would reference the correct class, but it doesnt and I still get the same error.

I'm using the following configuration to setup Tiles in my spring mvc app:

```
<beans:bean 
    id="tilesConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver">      
    <beans:property 
        name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>                
</beans:bean>
```

Ideally, I would like to get Spring 3.0.5 working with Tiles 2.2.2. They are the latest versions as of this post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`org.apache.tiles.startup.BasicTilesInitializer` is a class of `tiles-core(2.2.1).jar`. Check that you have deployed the `tiles-core` jar

Comment: @Athens, did you checked that the class is in the jar? And did you checked that the jar is really deployed to your Application Server?

Comment: I am using SpringSource Tools Suite and I am able to see the class when I inspect the referenced jar. I am not deploying to a remote server. I get the error when I run the app in debug mode via Debug As->Debug on Server. Do you think this is a configuration issue? Is Tiles 2.2.2 supported by Spring 3? According to the documentation of Spring's TilesConfigurer (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/tiles2/TilesConfigurer.html), it is. I just haven't been successful with it.

Comment: @Athens: If your App Server is an Tomcat, then STS/Eclipse will put the files in the project meteata directory: `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp<0>\wtpwebapps\<Applciation>\WEB-INF\lib`  - check this directory whether the jar is in it or not (I guess it is similar for other server)

Comment: it turns out that all i had to do was add the files to my WEB-INF\lib folder in my STS project. I had already added them to the build path and assumed they would be deployed with the rest of the WEB-INF artifacts. This was a tough lesson to learn. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Athens: (it seams that you are not using maven): You should put all for runtime required jars in the WEB-INF\lib folder, then you must not add them (a second time) explicite to your project.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, I do have my jars inside `/WEB-INF/lib` folder, but still no luck with Tiles. What could be wrong?

Comment: I'm using maven and I have the tiles-core dependency set, the jar is in local repository; but still when I run the project (after mvn install) I get ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.startup.BasicTilesInitializer. why?

Comment: I changed all tiles dependencies from version 2.2.2 to 2.2.1 and it started to work. hope this helps.

Answer (score 20):

For tiles 3, use class `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer`. Make sure you have that in `spring webmvc`.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using maven then you can add this dependency in order to solve the problem:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
     <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to apologize for reviving a stale thread.

I have a Spring MVC project built in Eclipse Helios.
I shut down Helios for a few days, then reopened it today.  When I ran my app, I got the same exception as above:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/startup/BasicTilesInitializer.

My solution was to clean the deploy directory on the integrated Tomcat server, then re-deploy the app.  The first time I redeployed, my app's lib dir showed only two jars.  So after cleaning and redeploying again, it then got all the necessary jar's and now my app runs again.  Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same problem, using version 2.2.2 of tiles. I switched to version 2.2.1 and it started to work. Here are my dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using STS and you created your project using a spring template project (like the MVC one) then you don't add anything to the lib directory. Instead you modify the pom.xml maven config file.

Answer (score 0):

I could only solve this after I added dependency to be provided at compile time in my POM

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following jars are on the application class-path:

1. commons-beanutils
2. commons-digester
3. log4j
4. slf4j-api
5. slf4j-log4j12
6. tiles-api
7. tiles-core
8. tiles-jsp
9. tiles-servlet
10. tiles-template

Version of tiles jars is depends on the version of Spring MVC. E.g. If Spring MVC 3.2.3 (org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer) is used then tile 3 jars are required.

Answer (score 0):

For tiles 3, you should add

> tiles-request.jar, 
>   commons-digester.jar