# Spring Tiles Integration Error

Tags: spring

I am trying to integrate Tiles 3.0.0 with Spring 3.1, I have all the tile jar files under my lib folder. When I run the web project I get an

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.startup.BasicTilesInitializer
```

error. I need some help understanding why I am getting this error. Here is my configuration to setup in my servlet.xml page.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesViewResolver" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is a question that's a lot like mine, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003995/spring-3-mvc-and-apache-tiles-2-integration-error), but I've already got my tiles-core-3.0.0 in my build path. So I just need some help understanding how to get over this error.

Morgan

Comment: Hello .. How did you run the web project ? Do you use tomcat ? Did you check in the servlet container that it has the tiles jar in the WEB-INF/lib ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing this, Spring still does not support Tiles 3. I'm using Spring 3.1.2 and had to downgrade Tiles back to version 2.2.2 in order for my application to run.

Answer (score 0):

I've make a program working with Spring Framework version 3.2.13.RELEASE and Tiles-3 (version 3.0.5). You need to use following configuration

```
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
</bean>
```

with dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Spring Web MVC -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I think this is what you're trying to achieve. It works fine in my case !