# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener when upgrading from 2.1.4 to 3.0.7 tiles jars

Tags: java, tiles

When upgrading tiles jars version  from 2.1.4 to 3.0.7, we are  facing

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.tiles.web.startup.TilesListener

We have few set of jars in tiles like

> tiles-jsp,tiles-api,tiles-core etc..

All these jars need to be  upgraded to 3.0.7.

This is a spring-project and I am not using any listeners as such for these jars .Any help would be appreciated to get rid of this run time exception.

TIA
Pradeep

Comment: im not sure check [this ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003995/spring-3-mvc-and-apache-tiles-2-integration-error)